# android sharedPreferences putString

Tags: android, fragment, sharedpreferences

i working sharedPreferences.i wrote code witch can to save information(some strings) and also can show this information in another fragment.now i want to recieve like this result.for example first time i saved 10 and then 20.in a another fragment i can show only 20,but i want to show sum this (10+20).meybe this question is  easy but i do not know how i can do this
this is  my source

```
private static String MY_PREFS = "mysessio";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        _price_counter_int = Integer.parseInt(price_counter
                        .getText().toString().trim());
                _price = _price * _price_counter_int;

                editor.putString("price",
                        String.valueOf(_price));
                editor.commit();
```

and another fragment code

```
 String MY_PREFS = "mysessio";
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
         String price_result;
    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    price_result = sharedPreferences.getString("price", "");


    int ab1 = Integer.parseInt(price_result);



    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(ab1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
```

Comment: Then what is the problem in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do something like this:
1. Before writing `20`, get the value `10`
2. Concatenate `20` with `10` with some character (Example 10:20)
3. At the time of getting sum, get the entire string (10:20)
4. Split the string with splitter character `:`
5. Get the sum

This will allow you to have access to all the consecutive additions to the `SharedPreferences`.

In case your only concern is to store the sum, you can directly get the value `10`, add `20` to it and commit the sum to `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

_price_counter_int = Integer.parseInt(price_counter.getText().toString().trim());
_price1 = _price * _price_counter_int;

editor.putString("price",String.valueOf(_price));
editor.putString("price1",String.valueOf(_price1));
editor.commit();
```

Then you can retrieve both the values and display them.